# How can I not track a directory in git locally?

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repository. Can I make it not track a directory?
I tried adding 'myIgnoreDirectory' to .gitignore and then 'rm -rf myIgnoreDirectory.

Then I do 'git status', I see a bunch of 'deleted files under myIgnoreDirectory'.

How can I get around that? I want to remove the 'myIgnoreDirectory'  locally to save disk space.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

git won't ignore tracked files.  You need to `git rm --cached` the directory you don't want to see anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned a github repo, fork it first, clone that, make a new branch, delete that directory, commit and work from there

Comment: you add it as another remote `git remote add upstream (read only url for the real repo)`. Then `git fetch upstream`. Now you can `git merge upstream/master`. If that dir changed, you will have conflicts - but they will be easily resolved.

Comment: note that not only does git already have the entire contents of the directory stored in `/.git`, but now you're adding a huge commit which deletes the entire contents again.  git is not really built to save disk space.  get a bigger hard drive?

Comment: That commit does not take any extra space on disk. When you checkout the other branch, yes, it will restore it again. To know exactly what's going on, take a look at an explanation of the DAG directed acyclic graph.